# Log Parsing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, logging

so this is a project that I am undertaking. I want to build a tool for log parsing with Javascript that takes in a couple of log files and then outputs a basic summary of the log messages such as time, thread name, log message...

**I know there are log parsing tools, I don't really care.

Example of the log file:

```
[2014-05-26 20:03:19,909] ERROR [ajp-apr-8009-exec-2] (ValidationUtils.java:74) Validation.validate field: id may not be null. The invalid value was: null 
[2014-05-26 20:03:34,031] ERROR [ajp-apr-8009-exec-4] (ValidationUtils.java:74) Validation.validate field: id may not be null. The invalid value was: null 
[2014-05-26 20:03:55,096] ERROR [ajp-apr-8009-exec-6] (ValidationUtils.java:74) Validation.validate field: id may not be null. The invalid value was: null 
[2014-05-26 20:04:23,492] ERROR [ajp-apr-8009-exec-7] (ValidationUtils.java:74) Validation.validate field: id may not be null. The invalid value was: null
```

Also, there are WARN and INFO messages, but I want to extract the most recent n (should be configurable) error messages and then display their summaries. 
Can anyone get me started, point me in the right direction and what not. I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are asking for, but here's what I did anyway:

```
^(\[[^\]]*\]) (\w+?) (\[[^\]]*\]) (\([^)]*\)) (.*)$
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vM2fZ0)